# Test if there are older posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've got this function:

```
<?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts') ); ?>
```

It creates a link if there are older posts. How do I do something on the condition that there are no older posts? Anything I do that uses this function only seems to echo the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a get_ to the function :)

```
<?php 
if (get_next_posts_link()) {}
?>
```